# Reorder factors numerically in a data frame

Tags: r, sorting

I have factors from 0 to 39. Here is how they are ordered now:

```
> levels(items$label)
 [1] "0"  "1"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19"
[13] "2"  "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "3" 
[25] "30" "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39" "4"  "5" 
[37] "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"
```

How do I reorder them in numeric order, for display purposes? I don't want to change the meaning of the data frame.

*UPDATE*: How do I update the original data frame, `items`, with the sorted factor, `labels`? This should not change the data frame substantively; I just want the factors to come out in the correct order in subsequent operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sorted_labels <- paste(sort(as.integer(levels(items$label))))
```

Gives:

```
 [1] "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11"
[13] "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23"
[25] "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32" "33" "34" "35"
[37] "36" "37" "38" "39"
```

Or (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15665655/109618):

```
sorted_labels <- order(levels(items$label)) - 1
# order by itself is a 1-based vector
# using `- 1` gives a 0-based vector
```

Per the updated question, this updates the data frame:

```
items$label <- factor(items$label, levels = sorted_labels)
```

Comment: you are using `paste()` instead of `as.character()`?

Answer (score 2):

If all the integers are present, then you can simply use `order`:

```
  order(levels(items$label)) - 1   # where the minus 1 is for starting from 0
```

If not all integers are present, then you have to use as.numeric, like you have it.

Comment: That's more concise. Per my updated question, how do I update the original data frame with the sorted levels?

Comment: @DavidJames  that sounds like a different question to me ;)

Comment: @DavidJames, you need to elaborate on what you mean by "update"   What is the final result you want?

Comment: `items$label <- factor(items$label, levels = order(levels(items$label)))` updates the original data frame with the reordered factor.

Comment: Note that `order` reindexes starting from 1: `order(c(0, 1, 2))` gives `1 2 3`.

Comment: I want to accept your answer, but first I would like it to include the `items$label <- factor(items$label, levels = order(levels(items$label)) - 1)` ... unless you think of a better way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27128/discussion-between-david-james-and-ricardo-saporta)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a `tidyverse` / `forcats` solution:

Generate data:

```r
items <- data.frame(label = as.character(0:39),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# if stringsAsFactors = TRUE (default), items$label must be converted to character before casting to integer!

factor(items$label)
#>  [1] 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
#> [24] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
#> 40 Levels: 0 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 ... 9
```

using `fct_relevel`

```r
library(forcats)

fct_relevel(items$label,function(x){as.character(sort(as.integer(x)))})
#>  [1] 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
#> [24] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
#> 40 Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 ... 39
```

it also works with `fct_reorder`

```r
fct_reorder(items$label,as.integer(items$label))
#>  [1] 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
#> [24] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
#> 40 Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 ... 39
```

which opens up some nice possibilities if your vector also includes character (eg. `1 egg`, `2 eggs` etc):

```r
items$label2 <- paste(items$label,"eggs")

factor(items$label2)
#>  [1] 0 eggs  1 eggs  2 eggs  3 eggs  4 eggs  5 eggs  6 eggs  7 eggs 
#>  [9] 8 eggs  9 eggs  10 eggs 11 eggs 12 eggs 13 eggs 14 eggs 15 eggs
#> [17] 16 eggs 17 eggs 18 eggs 19 eggs 20 eggs 21 eggs 22 eggs 23 eggs
#> [25] 24 eggs 25 eggs 26 eggs 27 eggs 28 eggs 29 eggs 30 eggs 31 eggs
#> [33] 32 eggs 33 eggs 34 eggs 35 eggs 36 eggs 37 eggs 38 eggs 39 eggs
#> 40 Levels: 0 eggs 1 eggs 10 eggs 11 eggs 12 eggs 13 eggs ... 9 eggs


library(readr)

fct_reorder(items$label2,parse_number(items$label2))
#>  [1] 0 eggs  1 eggs  2 eggs  3 eggs  4 eggs  5 eggs  6 eggs  7 eggs 
#>  [9] 8 eggs  9 eggs  10 eggs 11 eggs 12 eggs 13 eggs 14 eggs 15 eggs
#> [17] 16 eggs 17 eggs 18 eggs 19 eggs 20 eggs 21 eggs 22 eggs 23 eggs
#> [25] 24 eggs 25 eggs 26 eggs 27 eggs 28 eggs 29 eggs 30 eggs 31 eggs
#> [33] 32 eggs 33 eggs 34 eggs 35 eggs 36 eggs 37 eggs 38 eggs 39 eggs
#> 40 Levels: 0 eggs 1 eggs 2 eggs 3 eggs 4 eggs 5 eggs 6 eggs ... 39 eggs
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

All outputs of the fct_* functions can be written back to the original data. Eg:

```r
items$data <- fct_reorder(items$label,as.integer(items$label))
```